Infinite generation of subgroup of p-adic Galois group
It is well-known the the wildly ramified subgroup of the absolute Galois group of a $p$-adic field is infinitely topologically generated. Is the same true of the the absolute Galois group of the maximal cyclotomic extension of a $p$-adic field? Any reference is welcome.

This is true.
Let $F$ be a field. A general technique to show that $G_F$ is not finitely generated is to show that $\text{Hom}_{\text{cts}}(G_F,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ is infinite. If $G_F$ was finitely topologically generated, then the finite possible images of the finite number of generates would determine a homomorphism uniquely. When $\mu_p\subseteq F$, we are helped by Kummer theory, as we get isomorphisms
$$\text{Hom}_{\text{cts}}(G_F,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})\cong H^1(F,\mu_p)=F^\times/F^{\times p}.$$
Now we return to the specific problem. Let $K$ be a $p$-adic local field. We assume WLOG that $\mu_p\subseteq K$ because $K$ and $K(\mu_p)$ have the same maximal cyclotomic extension. Let $K_{\text{unr}}$ be the maximal unramified extension of $K$. We have isomorphisms (given by the Frobenius)
$$\text{Gal}(K_{\text{unr}}/K)\cong \hat{\mathbb{Z}}=\prod_p\mathbb{Z}_p.$$
Let $L$ be the fixed field of $\mathbb{Z}_p\subseteq \text{Gal}(K^{\text{unr}}/K)$. For integers $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $p\nmid n$, we have fields $K_n\subseteq L$ given by the fixed field of $n\hat{\mathbb{Z}}$. The group $H^1(L/K_n,\mu_p(L))$ vanishes because $L/K_n$ has no subextensions of order divisible by $p$. Then the inflation-restriction exact sequence
$$0\to H^1(L/K_n, \mu_p(L))\to H^1(K_n,\mu_p)\to H^1(L,\mu_p)$$
implies $\text{res}:H^1(K_n,\mu_p)\to H^1(L,\mu_p)$ is an injection for all $n$. The order of $H^1(K_n,\mu_p)\cong K_n^\times/K_n^{\times p}$ is $p^{[K_n:\mathbb{Q}_p]+2}$ by known results on the structure of the multiplicative group of a local field, so this implies $H^1(L,\mu_p)$ is infinite. Since $\mu_p\subseteq K\subseteq L$, we have that $G_L$ is not finitely generated by the discussion at the beginning of the answer.
We have an exact sequence of profinite groups
$$1\to G_{K_{\text{unr}}} \to G_{L}\to \mathbb{Z_p}\to 1$$
because $\text{Gal}(K_{\text{unr}}/L)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is finitely generated but $G_L$ is not, we get that $G_{K_{\text{unr}}}$ is not finitely generated, as otherwise the finite generators of $G_{K_{\text{unr}}}$ and a lift of a generator of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ would generate $G_L$. Let $K_{\text{cyc}}$ be the maximal cyclotomic extension of $K$. We repeat the above argument on the exact sequence
$$1\to G_{K_{\text{cyc}}}\to G_{K_{\text{unr}}}\to \mathbb{Z}_p\to 1$$
to obtain that $G_{K_{\text{cyc}}}$ is not finitely generated.
